# angularjs dropdown not working intermittently in chrome

Tags: html, angularjs

HTML:

```
<select id="bId"
    ng-options="b as b.name for b in books"
    ng-model="selectedBook"
    ng-change='onBookChange()'>
</select>
```

problem:
options are not displaying intermittently and selected option is also not visible.

options(name of the book):

[{"bookId":"1156","bookName":"Half GirlFriend"},{"bookId":"2016","bookName":"wings of fire"}]

Comment: Please add Fiddle/Plnkr.

Comment: b as b.name for b in books   {{ books }} check whether books have any values

Comment: @Niyaz {{books}} having values -->  [{"bookId":"1156","bookName":"Half GirlFriend"},{"bookId":"2016","bookName":"wings of fire"}]

Comment: ng-options="b.bookId as b.bookName for b in books"   have u tried this way ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="bId"
   ng-options="b.bookId as b.bookName for b in books track by $index"
   ng-model="selectedBook"
   ng-change='onBookChange()'>
</select>
```

track by $index will print the option if any duplication are there in the books array.

Answer (score 0):

`*.html` part use `b.bookName` instead of `b.name` in `ng-options` because that's the name in your `books` object

```
<select id="bId"
  ng-options="b as b.bookName for b in books" 
  ng-model="selectedBook"
  ng-change='onBookChange()'>
</select>
```

`*.js` part

```
$scope.books = [
                {"bookId":"1156","bookName":"Half GirlFriend"},    
                {"bookId":"2016","bookName":"wings of fire"}
               ];

$scope.selectedBook = $scope.books[0];
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TTBhwCqioKEELAGfkrwl?p=preview)

Comment: thanks @manish , working fine but intermittently options are not visible in chrome.